# blazor generic api that returns list of T

Tags: .net, api, generics, blazor

im building some blazor app
and would like to have some generic methods that can returns any type from shared project

so idea is that i would like to do

```
 List<GSPparam> parameters.... // stored proc params
 List<person> ret = await this._ihttp.Post<List<person>>("api/...",parameters )
```

and in api

```
 [HttpPost]
 [Route("...")]
 public async Task<T> ExecProcTable<T>( [FromBody] List<GSPparam> parameters)
{  
 ....
 somehow KNOWN WHAT THE T IS ?
 in this case List<person>
 so
 List<person> ret = ..... ;
 return ok (ret)
}
```

but i have no idea how to pass this Type from shared project
via string ? and some reflection?
please advice

regards

Comment: The question is unclear. First, Blazor itself doesn't affect generics, lists or APIs. Second, HttpClient already has generic methods, including extension methods like `PostAsJsonAsync` and `GetFromJsonAsync<>`.  Third, Blazor is an SPA framework, not a data access library, ORM or HTP API framework. `ExecProcTable` is an unusually named ASP.NET Core Web API action. You can't have a generic Web API action

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for something like GraphQL or OData? Using eg HotChocolate it's relatively easy to [expose EF entities through GraphQL](https://chillicream.com/docs/hotchocolate/integrations/entity-framework)

Comment: yes PostAsJsonAsync  is generic but then why in api recive this generic type ?

Comment: HTTP requests have no types, they have JSON bodies. The *action* specifies what types to use to deserialize that JSON. To handle multiple payload types, the *request* should specify what type to use using a custom header or field. That type must exist on the server, which means you now need a registry of types and their schema. That's not trivial. That's why GraphQL exists.

Comment: Check the EF+GraphQL link. It does what you want in a few lines, in a way that works with all GraphQL clients.

Comment: yes i will check thanks but in graphqu as fare as i known we have to write some resolvers for each type yes ? and i wanted to avoid that  for this 'simple' cases :P - just exec proc and return lisf of objects from db based on this params passed. and yes what is in shared project in blazor exists on client and on server both so only need to specyfy with is it

Comment: That's anything but a simple case. How could a remote server ever guess what type to use to deserialize a JSON string? A JSON object is actually a dictionary, so why shouldn't the server always work with `Dictionary<string,object>`? Why should it pick some other type? JSON only contains fields and values. *You* will have to include that type information, and use it on the server to decide what type to use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will answer my solution that i came with help of some other my stackoverflow topic  using reflection only  ;)

[using reflection execute generic method into list of type passed by string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73660337/using-reflection-execute-generic-method-into-list-of-type-passed-by-string)

im doing like

```
_ihttp.Post<IEnumerable<T>>("api/GSP/ExecProc/List/" + ProcedureName + "/"+ typeof(T).Name+ "/" + CommandTimeout.ToString(), _parameters, CommandTimeout + 5, cts);
```

so sending this T type as string in url

and in api controller

```
private static async Task<IEnumerable> AwaitQueryAsyncResult<T>(Task<IEnumerable<T>> task)
 => await task;


[HttpPost]
[Route("ExecProc/List/{SPname}/{TypeName}/{Timeout:int=30}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> ExecProcList(string SPname,string TypeName, int timeout , [FromBody] List<GSPparam> parameters)
{

 Type type = type = Type.GetType("XXX.Shared.Classes." + TypeName + ", XXX.Shared")!;

if (type is null) throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("type {0} not found", TypeName));


   IEnumerable l = (IEnumerable)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(type))!;

      
   System.Reflection.MethodInfo method = _sql.GetType().GetMethods().Where(c => c.Name == ("QueryAsync") && c.GetParameters()[1].ParameterType == typeof(List<GSPparam>)).First().MakeGenericMethod(new Type[] { type });
       
object[] args = { SPname, parameters, CommandType.StoredProcedure, timeout, "Default" };

        var task = method.Invoke(this._sql, args);

        var miAwaitQueryAsyncResult = typeof(GSPController).GetMethod(nameof(AwaitQueryAsyncResult), System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static)!
            .MakeGenericMethod(type);

        var resultAsEnumerable = await (Task<IEnumerable>)miAwaitQueryAsyncResult.Invoke(null, new[] { task })!;

        return Ok(resultAsEnumerable);
```

please let me known what do You think about this kind of solution . the type must be in shared classes namespace and thats it ?
Best regards

Comment: who / why -1? please write what You think.

Answer (score 0):

It's not easy as json has no concept of `T`.

Either use one of the systems out there suggested in the various comments or code your own.

My approach is to create a base controller.  This one is for a CQS data pipeline rather than the good old repository pattern but it demonstrates the concepts:

```cs
[ApiController]
public abstract class AppControllerBase<TRecord>
    : ControllerBase
    where TRecord : class, new()
{
    protected ICQSDataBroker _dataBroker;

    public AppControllerBase(ICQSDataBroker dataBroker)
        => _dataBroker = dataBroker;

    [Mvc.Route("/api/[controller]/listquery")]
    [Mvc.HttpPost]
    public async Task<ListProviderResult<TRecord>> ListQuery([FromBody] ListQuery<TRecord> query)
        => await _dataBroker.ExecuteAsync<TRecord>(query);

    [Mvc.Route("/api/[controller]/addrecordcommand")]
    [Mvc.HttpPost]
    public async Task<CommandResult> AddRecordCommand([FromBody] AddRecordCommand<TRecord> command)
        => await _dataBroker.ExecuteAsync<TRecord>(command);
/....
}
```

And then implement real controllers like this:

```cs
[ApiController]
public class DboWeatherForecastController : AppControllerBase<DboWeatherForecast>
{
    public DboWeatherForecastController(ICQSDataBroker dataBroker)
        : base(dataBroker)
    { }
}
```

The API databroker end for a call looks like this:

```cs
    public async ValueTask<ListProviderResult<TRecord>> ExecuteAsync<TRecord>(ListQuery<TRecord> query) where TRecord : class, new()
    {
        ListProviderResult<TRecord>? result = null;

        var entityname = (new TRecord()).GetType().Name;
        var response = await _httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync<ListQuery<TRecord>>($"/api/{entityname}/listquery", query);

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            result = await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<ListProviderResult<TRecord>>();

        return result ?? new ListProviderResult<TRecord>();
    }

    public async ValueTask<CommandResult> ExecuteAsync<TRecord>(AddRecordCommand<TRecord> command) where TRecord : class, new()
    {
        CommandResult? result = null;

        var entityname = (new TRecord()).GetType().Name;
        var response = await _httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync<AddRecordCommand<TRecord>>($"/api/{entityname}/addrecordcommand", command);

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            result = await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<CommandResult>();

        return result ?? new CommandResult();
    }
```

On the client side I have an API DataBroker with methods that look like this:

```cs
    public async ValueTask<ListProviderResult<TRecord>> ExecuteAsync<TRecord>(ListQuery<TRecord> query) where TRecord : class, new()
    {
        ListProviderResult<TRecord>? result = null;

        var entityname = (new TRecord()).GetType().Name;
        this.SetHTTPClientSecurityHeader();
        var response = await _httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync<ListQuery<TRecord>>($"/api/{entityname}/listquery", query);

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            result = await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<ListProviderResult<TRecord>>();

        return result ?? new ListProviderResult<TRecord>();
    }

    public async ValueTask<CommandResult> ExecuteAsync<TRecord>(AddRecordCommand<TRecord> command) where TRecord : class, new()
    {
        CommandResult? result = null;

        var entityname = (new TRecord()).GetType().Name;
        this.SetHTTPClientSecurityHeader();
        var response = await _httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync<AddRecordCommand<TRecord>>($"/api/{entityname}/addrecordcommand", command);

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            result = await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<CommandResult>();

        return result ?? new CommandResult();
    }

    protected virtual void SetHTTPClientSecurityHeader()
    {
        // add your security headers
    }
```

(I've not included all the security, exception handling and bad response stuff to keep it simple).

Comment: can you show how post request looks like ? so it satisfy [FromBody] ListQuery<TRecord> query ? this is the place from witch TRecord type is captured right ?

Comment: See my updated answer.