# using reflection execute generic method into list of type passed by string

Tags: c#, reflection, blazor

I need to based on string type - for example 'UserModel'
execute method

```
  Task<IEnumerable<T>> QueryAsync<T>(string sqlStatment, DynamicParameters parameters, CommandType commandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure, int timeout = 90, string connectionId = "Default");
```

so I have

```
  string TypeName = "UserModel";
    Type type = Type.GetType("XXX.Shared.CoreClasses."+ TypeName+", XX.Shared")!;
    if(type is null) throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("type {0} not found", TypeName));


    IList l = (IList)Activator
    .CreateInstance(typeof(List<>)
    .MakeGenericType(type))!;

    System.Reflection.MethodInfo method = _sql.GetType().GetMethods().Where(c => c.Name == ("QueryAsync") 
        && c.GetParameters()[1].ParameterType == typeof(DynamicParameters)).First().MakeGenericMethod(new Type[] { type });

   object[] args = { SPname,d, CommandType.StoredProcedure,timeout };//not relevant
```

so now how to fill this `l` list with this method ?

like

```
 l= await method.Invoke(this, args)!;
```

- it yeals at me about casting / object canot be awaited ?
  how to do this properly ?
  is something like this slow ? or nowdays it does not matter until it will have to execute like xxxx times/sec ?
  thanks and regards !

Comment: Pay attention to your `QueryAsync` method. What again is its return type?

Comment: "how to do this properly ? is something like this slow ?" What do you exactly mean here? What result do you expect? Apart from this we cannot forsee if this might be slow, you should measure it doing it some millions of times.

Comment: IEnumerable<T> is return type?. i expect more or less  5 executions /sec so i think this should not matter at all ?

Comment: No, that's not the return type. Why don't you take a look at the method declaration? There's no guess work needed here. ;-)

Comment: Task<IEnumerable<T>> ok i see :/ ;P

Comment: So, is a `Task<IEnumerable<T>>` value assignable to a variable that's typed `IList`? And have you ever done some basic async programming in C# using the async/await keywords?

Comment: You cannot *cast*  to `T`, as you don't know `T` at compile-time.

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain, dOOlar is using reflection. And of course if a generic method can be reflected upon including a concrete type parameter, then for sure the code will (or rather can) also know what type of `T` is in the returned `Task<IEnumerable<T>>`... basically the same type that is used in `MakeGenericMethod(new Type[] { type }`...  ;-)

Comment: ok guys thanks i see so how to cast this method invoke into task so it can be awaited ?

Comment: @my of course that's possible, but not at **compile-time**, which is what casting is for. All OP will ever get from `Invoke` is an unspecific `object` or at best an **ungeneric** `IEnumerable`.

Comment: Yes, it can be awaited. One more thing. The type you are using as generic type parameter, can you ensure that it will always be a reference type?

Comment: yes here always - only clases that will be  in this specyfic namespace

Comment: so can You please help me ? do You known how to do it ?

Comment: @d00lar, patience (i actually came up with a solution that is not restricted to reference types, but i will take some time for a write up)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `QueryAsync<T>` method returns a `Task<IEnumerable<T>>` instance.

But the result of calling this method through reflection via `method.Invoke(this, args)` is type-cast as `object`, and since the type for the generic type parameter is given as a type name string, it is impossible here to cast directly to Task<IEnumerable<*TypeIdentifier*>> and await it, because the *TypeIdentifier* has to be known and specified in the source code at compile-time.

```
object task = method.Invoke(this, args)!;
```

Although, from the question it looks like the *QueryAsync* method is an instance of the type of the variable *_sql*. Therefore, possibly the correct way to invoke this method is perhaps:

```
object task = method.Invoke(_sql, args)!;
```

But how can we await the task then and get the result? Another small static helper method will solve this issue. We are calling it through reflection again, thus avoiding the impossible step of casting the object-typed QueryAsync<T> result as some Task<IEnumerable<*TypeIdentifier*>> in our source code.

```
private static async Task<IEnumerable> AwaitQueryAsyncResult<T>(Task<IEnumerable<T>> task)
    => await task;
```

Note the return type. It's a task returning `IEnumerable` (which works because *IEnumerable<T>* inherits *IEnumerable*). In some sense we basically "converted" a *Task<IEnumerable<TypeIdentifier>>* we are unable to specify in the source code to a *Task<IEnumerable>* - a concrete type that can be specified in the source code. No more generic type parameter anymore we don't know about at compile-time!

From here on, it's pretty much straightforward. We will call our little generic helper method *AwaitQueryAsyncResult<T>* through reflection in similar fashion as has been done with the *QueryAsync<T>* method:

```
...

object task = method.Invoke(this, args)!;


var miAwaitQueryAsyncResult = typeof(TheTypeWhereAwaitQueryAsyncResultIsDeclared)
    .GetMethod(nameof(AwaitQueryAsyncResult), System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static)
    .MakeGenericMethod(type);

var resultAsEnumerable = await (Task<IEnumerable>) miAwaitQueryAsyncResult.Invoke(null, new[] { task } );
```

With *QueryAsync<T>*'s result now available as usefully typed `resultAsEnumerable` variable, it should be not too difficult to iterate/loop over it and add its elements to the list in the *IList*-typed variable `l`. I will leave the implementation of this little loop as a coffee-time exercise to the reader ;-)

Comment: thanks bu object task = method.Invoke(new UserModel(), args); is still using type tkat mus be known at compile time. String type "UserModel" is just example - it will be many types possible here.

and also it still throws       System.Reflection.TargetException: Object does not match target type.
 at object task = method.Invoke(new UserModel(), args); line

Comment: @d00lar, ah, lol, stupid mistake by me. That line was from my test code, and i completely missed replacing it with your actual `method.Invoke(this, args)!;` there. It is fixed now. My apologies...

Comment: it still throws XXX.Client.Core.HttpClients.GSPService[0]
      System.Reflection.TargetException: Object does not match target type.
         at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
         at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[] parameters)
         at XXX.Server.Controllers.GSPController.ExecProcTable(String SPname, Int32 timeout, List`1 parameters) in  at line object task = method.Invoke(this, args)!

Comment: if it helps i see in debug that the 'method' is : {System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[XXX.Shared.CoreClasses.UserModel]] QueryAsync[UserModel](System.String, Dapper.DynamicParameters, System.Data.CommandType, Int32, System.String)}

Comment: i did try  Task<IEnumerable<UserModel>> task = (Task<IEnumerable<UserModel>>)method.Invoke(this, args)! but the same -object does not match... var task.. also

Comment: @d00lar, you'll need to invoke the `QueryAsync` method on an instance of the type that declares QueryAsync. Currently, you are using `this`. So, ask and answer yourself: Is `this` an object instance of the type declaring `QueryAsync`? If not, note that you are actually querying the type of the variable `_sql` for the `QueryAsync` method. Again, ask and answer yourself: Are `this` and `_sql` variables/instances of the same type that declares QueryAsync?

Comment: thanks alot - i was thinking about that but assumed that method info somehow contains this object itself ant this is just like parrent type 
thanks alot regards !

Comment: and for future searchers
         var task = method.Invoke(this._sql, args);
so simple.